# how to send a mysql line, in php, from online host to distant wamp server database?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, virtualhost

as i explained in the title, i try to send a php mysql request from my infomaniak website to a distant wampserver database. my goal is that each time a user complete the form on the website, datas are send to the mysql website database and also to the distant mysql wamp database.

Website side :

i chose regular solution with infomaniaks to host my website (if you want to know)

Here is the code i used to send :

```
$servname2 = 'xx.xx.xx.xx'; #public ip of the distant server
$user2 = 'xxxxxxxx';
$pass2 = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

$dbname2 = 'borne_event';
$table2 = 'test3';

try {
    #var_dump($servname2);
    $conn = new mysqli($servname2, $user2, $pass2);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $dbco2 = new PDO("mysql:host=servname2;dbname=dbname2", $user2, $pass2);//;port=3306
    $dbco2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sth2 = $dbco2->prepare("INSERT INTO test3(idBorne, mail,genre, nom, 
                                prenom, telephone, codePostal, validationCDU, 
                                majeur, validationNL) 
                        VALUES (:IDBorne,:Mail, :Genre,:Nom,
                                :Prenom, :Telephone, :CodePostal, :ValidCDU,
                                :Majeur, :NewsLetter)");

    $sth2->execute(array(
            ':IDBorne' => $ID_Borne,
            ':Mail' => $Mail,
            ':Genre' => $genre,
            ':Nom' => $Nom,
            ':Prenom' => $prenom,
            ':Telephone' => $Telephone,
            ':CodePostal' => $CoPo,
            ':ValidCDU' => $Valid_CDU,
            ':Majeur' => $date_naissance,
            ':NewsLetter' => $NL)
        );

    echo 'Entrée ajoutée dans la table';
}
```

this code works well when i configure it for insert datas in the database website and does'nt seems to be the problem.

Wamp server side :

i have a regular wamp installation with mysql database, both (wamp and online sever) have the same structure. i get internet with 4g box

i followed this guide https://jasondarkx2.com/how-to-put-wampserver-online/

1. get my ipV4 from cmd -> ipconfig (maybe should i get it static)
2. modifications in httpd-vhosts.conf, i did :

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#  ServerName localhost
#  ServerAlias localhost
#  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
#  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
#    AllowOverride All
#    Allow from all
#    #Require all granted
#  </Directory>
#</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName rborne.com
  ServerAlias rborne.com *.rborne.com
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/rborne"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/rborne">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Require all granted

  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3. i went to windows defender and add a rule for inbounds : Rule Type:Port, Protocol and Port: TCP, specific local port: 80, Action: Allow the connection, Profile : All
4. i went to hosts file -> C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and had those lines :

```
xx.xx.xx.xx rborne.com # ipv4 of the machine
xx.xx.xx.xx www.rborne.com # same ipv4
```

5. in the end i went to the internet rooter and did a port redirection ->
   name : mysqlaccess,
   port internal : 3306,
   port external : 3306,
   protocole : TCP,
   machine : xx.xx.xx.xx #ipv4 of the machine,
   IP specific : none (during the test, will be replace by website IP)

Every time I complete the form on my website, i'm getting a time out.
I also try to ping the IP via the cmd but, i dont have any answer.

Did i miss something ? or did something wrong,

Please let me know if you have a solution to share,
Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you sure that distant server accepts connection from *its* outside? In most cases by default MySQL accepts localhost only. Check it first. One of the easiest way i strying to login from terminal like `mysql -h distant.server.com -u username -p`

Comment: _Small Point_ Putting the domain in the HOSTS file only effects that PC, and attempts to access those domain names from the one PC

Comment: @biesior, i'm very new about network, Which terminal should i use ? the one with wamp server install on ?or a other machine. about the command, does it work on windows cmd ? and do i have to change something like : `mysql -h rborne.com -u myusername -p mypassword` ?

Comment: It would be better to use a proper API for this. Don't try to access the remote database directly

Comment: Yes i am currently trying to do it with an api rest in php. trought this page : https://waytolearnx.com/2019/07/creer-et-utiliser-une-api-rest-en-php.html but it still don't work. i have acces to my php distant folder with the right public IP but when i make a request from my online website in php to put datas in the local database nothing happen